# Objective C - How to use OC Mock?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmock

I have a class that suppose to return a string when a method gets called. How can i create a mock object.

I want mock to return @"Hello" when the method "sayHello" get's called

```
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MyCrazyClass class]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[[mock stub] andReturn:@"Hello"] yourMethod:someArgument];
```

Comment: I get the following warning "No -andReturn: method found"

Comment: #import <OCMock/OCMock.h> I had to import this